# How to Create a Single Design of widgets in python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

As you can see, fonts (name, size, style, etc.) are repeated in every `Checkbutton`. How can I create a single design for them while not repeating the same code in every `Checkbutton`? Thanks

```
main.iconify()
    global motor_wire
    motor_wire = Toplevel(main)


motorframe = LabelFrame(motor_wire, text="SIZE OF WIRE", font = ('Garamond', '25', 'bold', 'underline'), padx = 270, pady = 167, bd = 8)
motorframe.place(x = 30, y = 5)
Label(motorframe).pack()

thirteen = Checkbutton(motor_wire, text = '#13',font=("Calibri", '30', 'bold'), relief = 'groove' ,
                       bd = 5,padx = 0, pady = 5).place(x = 52, y = 50)
fourteen = Checkbutton(motor_wire, text = '#14',font=("Calibri", '30', 'bold'),relief = 'groove' ,
                       bd = 5,padx = 0, pady = 5).place(x = 189, y = 50)
fifteen = Checkbutton(motor_wire, text = '#15',font=("Calibri", '30','bold'),relief = 'groove' ,
                        bd = 5, padx = 0, pady = 5).place(x = 326, y = 50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a dictionary of the repeated attributes:

```
d = dict(font=("Calibri", '30', 'bold'), relief='groove', bd=5, padx=0, pady=5)
```

Then unpack it into the constructor:

```
thirteen = Checkbutton(motor_wire, text='#13', **d)
```

Remember not to chain the placement method, or you won't be able to refer back to the widget later:

```
thirteen.place(x=52, y=50)
```

Also consider using a list for these checkbuttons, so you can create `thirteen`, `fourteen`, etc. (presumably from `one` or `zero`, too) in a loop:

```
buttons = []
for i in range(15):
    buttons.append(Checkbutton(motor_wire, text=f'#{i}', **d))
# manual placement with .place() afterward, or maybe check out .grid()
```